# CRM Plugin - Missing Attributes in Linq result

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-entities, dynamics-crm-2011

I encountered some strange behavior while working with a plugin for MSCRM 2011.
The code below is part of a plugin registered on the create & update action on the product entity. 
Each product has a couple of tasks (defined as an activity entity) related to it and I want the open tasks of the product as a result.

```
var tasks = from t
            in orgContext.CreateQuery("fvm_producttask") 
            where (t.GetAttributeValue<int>("statuscode") != 2 && t.GetAttributeValue<int>("statuscode") != 3)
            where t.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("fvm_regardingproduct").Id == product.Id
            select t;

String xx = "";
foreach (String x in tasks.First().Attributes.Keys) {
    xx += x + "\r\n";
}

throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(xx);
```

When I execute the code above as a CRM plugin I get only 2 keys in my result (subject, activityid), when i remove the second where clause I get the desired result of all keys from the producttask entity.

Anyone knows the reason for this behavior? 
I know I can solve this by filtering out all the tasks for other products out afterwards but this is only a (dirty) workaround. I'd like to know why the code above won't work.

Below you can check out the record I want to retrieve.

```
OwnerId                         FA7AF161-D666-E111-8537-001E4F1285B0 
OwningUser                      FA7AF161-D666-E111-8537-001E4F1285B0
OwningTeam                      NULL
OwningBusinessUnit              168D9521-434E-E111-99C9-001E4F1285B0
ActualEnd                       NULL
VersionNumber                   0x00000000002D40BD
ActivityId                      655E63A1-84B9-E311-A79F-005056A56527
IsBilled                        0
CreatedBy                       FA7AF161-D666-E111-8537-001E4F1285B0
Description                     Product Dimensions Required
ModifiedOn                      2014-04-01 14:07:11.000
ServiceId                       NULL
ActivityTypeCode                10134
StateCode                       0
ScheduledEnd                    2014-04-04 10:01:45.000
ScheduledDurationMinutes        4320        
ActualDurationMinutes           NULL
StatusCode                      1
ActualStart                     NULL
CreatedOn                       2014-04-01 10:01:45.000
PriorityCode                    1
RegardingObjectId               NULL
Subject                         Product Requires Attention
IsWorkflowCreated               0
ScheduledStart                  2014-04-01 10:01:45.000
ModifiedBy                      FA7AF161-D666-E111-8537-001E4F1285B0
TimeZoneRuleVersionNumber       0
UTCConversionTimeZoneCode       NULL
InstanceTypeCode                0
SeriesId                        NULL
IsRegularActivity               1
ModifiedOnBehalfBy              FA7AF161-D666-E111-8537-001E4F1285B0
CreatedOnBehalfBy               NULL
TransactionCurrencyId           NULL
ExchangeRate                    NULL
LeftVoiceMail                   0
IsMapiPrivate                   0
RegardingObjectTypeCode         NULL
RegardingObjectIdName           NULL 
ImportSequenceNumber            NULL
OverriddenCreatedOn             NULL
fvm_RegardingProduct            207592F0-E9B8-E311-A79F-005056A56527
fvm_Category                    1
```

Comment: Could you include data from a sample task that is tied to your fvm_regardingproduct?  I have seen scenarios where the Key doesn't exist in the attributes collection at all when the value is null.  In general, I prefer using the strongly typed, generated proxy types over the attributes collection for that reason.

Comment: Do you have any field level security going on?

Comment: @Daryl No I don't have any.

Comment: I did some debugging and found out that every task of the product the plugin is executed on only returns 2 attributes, the tasks of other products seem to return all attributes. 
Is it possible that the plugin locks some fields during execution and that's why I don't get all attributes?

Comment: @Vosje Do the tasks exist before the plugin is ran?  I'd turn on CRM tracing and verify that the SQL statement that is getting generated looks like it should.

Comment: @Daryl The plugin also does generate the tasks if they don't exist yet. In this case they already exist so he skips the first part of the plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might be that the entity you are referencing has locked fields.

Do you do any operations earlier in the program flow?

Maybe try to Dispose() the context before the CreateQuery.. (or, if relevant, wrap the preceding context initialization in a using block )

HTH
Bob

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the problem. I had the OrganizationServiceContext declared globally in the plugin and initialized it once when executing the plugin. By declaring it locally in every function using it, the problem went away.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my problem too. I re-instantiated the ServiceContext object.

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't have any locked fields. This problem has been my nemesis and your Dispose() trick worked beautifully. My question is - why is this happening? How did you figure this solution out? Where can I learn more about the inner workings Is the Using block a best practice for wrapping all my LINQ queries?

Comment: @Eccountable you are very welcome, using blocks are just syntactic sugar around a try finally block calling Dispose() in the finally clause, so do whatever is most pleasing to your eye :)

Answer (score 0):

When working with the CRM SDK, it will only return attributes that have a value for them.  I'm guessing your first task has all values null except for the Subject and ActivityId.

Comment: I did look up the Activity in the database with the specified ID and found the value I wanted there, so they are not null. He just seems to have a problem retrieving them.